# PHP PHARs with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I've been thinking of advantages and disadvantages of distributing my app as a single PHAR.

I'd still like to use Composer to manage all the random dependencies I have, though. This means writing back to the phar if stuff changes, which I understand is at best a convoluted process.

What's the best way of reconciling that? Should I simply keep my app self-contained and have it work with an external /vendor dir?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the [composer.phar](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/composer.json) file itself includes a few Symfony components, as well as some other libraries written by the author, and they are all put into the .phar file for distribution (including, explicitly, [a number of vendor/ sub-directories](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/e64470c987fdd6bff03b85eed823eb4b865a4152/src/Composer/Compiler.php#L107)), it doesn't seem unreasonable to also include the required vendor directories for your own project.

Comment: With your approach, what happens when a vendor makes an update? Composer updates your copy?

Comment: @iroegbu You have an "unpharred" copy that is for development. When a vendor updates, or you do, you would work in the regular project just like you would right now. When you're ready to distribute the new version, you package things up in a new phar, push it to your master repo, and that build is your "release".

Comment: Works for me! Any disadvantages to this approach?

Comment: Phar files usually work great for command line applications. It'll introduce a "compilation" step into your distribution workflow which add all necessary files to the phar file. You should think about how to update an already deployed phar file (like `composer self-update`) as well, while not forgetting the security aspects of it.